# Best way to visualizing cluster memberships in a numpy array

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, visualization

I have an original numpy array of size 13,500 and 3D shape of (15, 30, 30) named 'my_original_data'. I have created 3 features based on class membership of that original array as below named 'my_cluster_df'. I was wondering if there is any best way to visualize these two (my_original_data and the my_cluster_df membership values) side by side so that it can be visualized each value (grid) in each layer of the original dataset (For simplicity, I have focused on one layer of that data only) correspond to which percentage of the class provided membership. An ideal visualization would include the original heatmap data (30 by 30 heatmap numpy array) side by side another with the best visualization for the 3 membership classes for each individual grid in that original 30 by 30 numpy array. I hope that I explained well.

My data, and code attempt is provided below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

my_original_data = np.random.rand(13500).reshape(15, 30, 30)

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

X = np.c_[    rng.normal(loc=25, scale=15, size=4500),    rng.normal(loc=65, scale=15, size=4500),    rng.normal(loc=115, scale=15, size=4500),].reshape(-1, 1)

model = GaussianMixture(n_components=3, random_state=42)
model.fit(X)

my_cluster_df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(model.predict_proba(X), 3), columns=["Class_Membership_1", "Class_Membership_2", "Class_Membership_3"])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
x = np.array(my_cluster_df["Class_Membership_1"])
y = np.array(my_cluster_df["Class_Membership_2"])
z = np.array(my_cluster_df["Class_Membership_3"])
ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker="s", c=my_cluster_df.index, s=40, cmap="RdBu")
plt.show()

side_by_side = np.hstack([
    np.array(my_original_data[0, 0:30, 0:30].reshape(30, 30)),
    np.array(my_cluster_df["Class_Membership_1"].head(30 * 30).to_numpy().reshape(30, 30)),
    np.array(my_cluster_df["Class_Membership_2"].head(30 * 30).to_numpy().reshape(30, 30)),
    np.array(my_cluster_df["Class_Membership_3"].head(30 * 30).to_numpy().reshape(30, 30))
])
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This question needs some major editing. `my_original_data` and `X` are sampled independently from one another: so it does not make sense to visualize them together. For example, look at the result of `plt.imshow(my_original_data[0])`, it's a 30x30 matrix of completely random noise. On the other hand: `X` and the Gaussian mixture have some structure that *can be visualized*. I suggest you either: (1) give a sample of what your actual data looks like and focus on `my_original_data`, or (2) focus on the GMM.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to reproduce my actual data but I was not successful. I thought given these two datasets, if the visualization worked, It would also work for my dataset.

Comment: As written, I have to *guess* what all of these things mean. This still could be a good question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! (e.g. here a sample of my geospatial data showing average temperature in a 30x30 grid, and here is a vector of all temperatures).